# Is the inclusion $i : A \to M$ smooth even if $A$ is not a submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Suppose $A \subset M$ is a subset of a smooth manifold $M$ and $A$ is also a smooth manifold with some arbitrary topology and smooth structure. $A$ is therefore just some arbitrary subset that also turns out to be a smooth manifold.

It seems to me that the inclusion $i : A \to M$ is then a smooth map as its restriction on any open subset $U \subset A$ equals the identity on the open submanifold $U$ in $A$:
$$
i\big|_U = \text{id}_U : U \to U,
$$
which is smooth. I am following John Lee in his introduction to smooth manifolds, but he seems to state the result only if $A$ is a submanifold of some kind. Could you clarify if I am right or wrong? And in the case I am wrong, please explain why.

Comment: What is your definition of smooth? My definition of smooth goes something like: for any point $p \in A$, there is a chart $(U, \psi)$ about $p$ in $A$ and a chart $(V, \phi)$ about $i(p)$ in $M$ (containing $i(U)$) such that the induced map $\phi \circ i \circ \psi^{-1} \colon \psi(U) \to \phi(V)$ is smooth. There is no reason why this should be the case if $A$ is equipped with a smooth structure which is not compatible with the smooth structure on $M$ in some essential way.

Comment: I think I can see where you're getting confused: you are assuming that the identity map is always smooth, irrespective of the associated smooth structure on the domain and target. If I'm not mistaken, this need not be the case! (Consider charts belonging to different maximal atlases.)

Comment: Let $M = \Bbb{R}^2$ and $A = [0,1)\times 0 \cup 0\times [0,1)$, the chart $\phi(t) = (\max(0,t),\min(0,t))$ makes $A$ a smooth manifold isomorphic to $(-1,1)$, the map $\phi : (-1,1) \to A\to M$ is continuous but not $C^1$ or smooth. Your claims holds if $A$ inherits from $M$'s topology : if $f \in C^\infty(M)$ implies $f|_A \in C^\infty(A)$ (with my example it doesn't hold with $f(x,y) = x$ as $f \circ \phi(t) = \max(0,t)$ isn't smooth)

Comment: For an arbitrary subset $A\subset M$, some authors say $f\colon A\to N$ is smooth if for every $p\in A$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ and a smooth extension $\tilde f\colon U\to N$ of $f$.

Comment: Alex Wertheim, if you want to copy and paste your comment into an answer, I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definition of a *smooth map of manifolds* $f : M \to N$ depends on charts on $M$ and $N$. If your subset has no charts, it does not seem to me that you can properly talk about smoothness.

Comment: $A$ has a smoothie structure, so it has a chart.

Comment: @MikkelRev as a submanifold, not as a subset

Comment: As I commented above, you can define smoothness on arbitrary subsets by requiring local smooth extensions.